# replace android intent chooser dialog

Tags: android, android-intent

is there a way to replace the intent-chooser dialog? At the moment my app is having heaps of intent-filters to come close to this - but I would like to explore other options ( also only working on rooted devices is an option in this case )
I mainly want to achieve these goals:
 - not having the default intent-chooser any more before my app
 - being registered to all intents

also just getting closer to just one of these goals would be nice - anyone here sees an option to do what I want to do?

Comment: Do you want to replace the default intent chooser for *all* apps, or only for intents launched from *your* app?

Comment: I want to do it for all apps - kind of really replace the existing chooser logic

Comment: Gotcha, just wanted to clarify. If you wanted to change it only for your app, you could implement your own. To replace it for all, you'd need to replace parts of the framework, afaik.

Comment: Sounds like the question of a malware author who is up to some very, very evil mischief.

Comment: not at all - just trying out some ideas for an involved intent-chooser dialog which - at the moment - is basically the same as in the first versions of android. There is much room for improvement in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

This is supported by the system. All you need to do is to create an `Activity` that has an [`Intent.CHOOSER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER) Intent filter.

Here is the definition of the one by default in Android:

```xml
<activity android:name="com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.Alert"
    android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:multiprocess="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: dam - sounded soo good but just tried this and it is not working :-(